# How can I fix this query (IN-clause) so that SQL server performance does not degrade when there is a low volume of data?

Tags: sql-server, performance

The following chart shows the performance of a process over time.

[image: Process performance over time]

The process is calling a stored procedure with the following form:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetResultSetsAndResultsWhereStatusIsValidatedByPatientId]
    @PatientId uniqueidentifier
AS

BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT resultSetTable.ResultSetId,
        resultSetTable.OrderId,
        resultSetTable.ReceivedDateTime,
        resultSetTable.ProfileId,
        resultSetTable.Status,
        profileTable.Code,
        testResultTable.AbnormalFlag,
        testResultTable.Result,
        orderTable.ReceptionDateTime,
        testTable.TestCode,
        orderedProfileTable.[Status] as opStatus
    FROM dbo.ResultSet resultSetTable
        INNER JOIN dbo.[Profile] profileTable on (profileTable.ProfileId = resultSetTable.ProfileId)
        INNER JOIN dbo.[TestResult] testResultTable on (testResultTable.ResultSetId = resultSetTable.ResultSetId)
        INNER JOIN dbo.[Order] orderTable on (resultSetTable.OrderId = orderTable.OrderId)
        INNER JOIN dbo.[Test] testTable on (testResultTable.TestId = testTable.TestId)
        INNER JOIN dbo.OrderedProfile orderedProfileTable on (orderedProfileTable.ProfileId = resultSetTable.ProfileId)
    WHERE orderTable.PatientId = @PatientId
        AND orderedProfileTable.[Status] in ('V', 'REP')
END
```

The problem seems to be the IN-clause. If I remove the IN-clause and only check for one of the values then I get consistent performance as seen in the second part of the graph.

```
AND orderedProfileTable.[Status] = 'V'
```

The issue also seems to be related to the amount of data in the tables. Only two tables grow, [ResultSet] and [TestResult], and both these tables are empty at the start of performance runs.

I have tried the following:

1. Move the IN-clause to a an outer select - no effect
2. Replace the IN-clause with a join - severe performance degradation
3. Create an index for the "Status" field used in the IN-clause - no effect

Is there a way to always get the low performance even when there is no data in the two relevant tables?

Comment: What does the plan say?

Comment: Have you tried using OR or even using UNION?

Comment: "both these tables are empty at the start of performance runs". When you actually create the proc it caches a plan based on the data on the tables, which might be empty. It continues to use this plan when the tables fill up, even if it is inefficient. You most likely have an incorrect cached plan for the stored procedure. The hacky fix is to add `with recompile` to the stored procedure.

Comment: Use this to work out if you have a parameter sniffing or bad query plan issue: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/

Comment: If you are changing your proc to change the IN clause _in the middle of_ your tests, it's possible what's happening is that really your proc has it's plan rebuilt with real data and is suddenly more efficient. Hard to say but this can be confirmed by various methods.

Comment: Mohammad: I tried OR, same behaviour. Didn't try UNION yet.

Comment: Nick: I tried WITH RECOMPILE and also tried OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) and the performance pattern looks exactly the same. The RECOMPILE one seems to have a noticeable negative effect on performance as well but both runs slowed gradually till about 47-48% of the test data and then dropped to a more stable performance like in the graph shown.

I have seen similar behaviour before in SQL server and I think we were able to fix it with an appropriate index. It seems like SQL server chooses a query plan and then at some critical point it decides to optimize and probably rebuilds the plan.

Comment: Every test run uses exactly the same data. Before a run all test data is deleted from the DB, the DB itself is not deleted, the stored procs, queries and statistics are not deleted. I just run a few DELETE statements against the relevant tables.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried throwing the IN query into an EXIST clause?

```
WHERE 
    orderTable.PatientId = @PatientId
    AND
    EXISTS
        (SELECT *
        FROM dbo.OrderedProfile as p
        WHERE
            p.profileid = orderedprofiletable.profileid
            AND
            [Status] IN ('v','rep'))
```

Since you're only searching for static results ('v' and 'rep') I would think that the IN clause by itself would be your best bet, but EXIST can sometimes speed up performance so it's worth a shot.

Comment: Awesome! This appears to work. I am noticing a slight drop in performance, will do some more testing. Currently I am pushing through about 800 operations so I'll scale that up to see if the performance stays predictable.

Comment: I ran into more performance problems when I scaled up. Turns out the problem is a logic error and nothing to do with the IN-clause. Interesting that EXISTS resulted in a different pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not related to the IN-clause in the end but a logic error. We started questioning why the query needed DISTINCT and when we removed it we discovered a logic error in the last join (needed some more criteria in what it matches against).

The error has been partially resolved and the performance issue seems to be resolved.

[image: Performance]

The stored procedure now completes in less than 10 ms on average and no performance degradation.